# custom static block widget not displaying in any frontend pages - Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In magento admin section, i have created a static block and added content into it. Then created a widget instance and selected this static block. And in layout update, i selected this widget to display on all pages with right column and in all product types, product view extra hint.

But, the widget is not appearing in any of the pages. May i know what the issue is for not displaying the widget.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I found the issue what stopped from displaying the widget in front end pages. Design Package/Theme should be default/default while creating the widget instance. Modifying the theme to default/default package, the widget displays in all pages.

Comment: Awesome! It saved our day. We were looking every where for the issue until I found this. One of our team members changed layout/template and suddenly widgets disappeared. This fixed the issue. You should accept this answer :)

Comment: I do not fully understand your answer. What do you mean by modify the theme to default/default package?
When you develop a custom theme you would like to name it somehow and take it distinguished from the demo theme named default/default

Answer (score 0):

if you have added **CATALOG CATEGORY WIDGET** widget in cms block from Magento admin, and your widget is not visible on front-end, then check **url_rewrite** table, if the mentioned category doesn't exist in url_rewrite table, then Please add new url rewrite for that category, and it will get displayed on front-end.